# Determine the position of an element relative to a positioned ancestor of its offset parent

Tags: jquery, dom, position, offset

I want to determine `#target`'s offset relative to `#a` in the following HTML document – i.e., I want to find the values of `x` and `y`:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2792776/screenshots/2012-06-09_1814.png

jQuery has `position()`, but `$("#target").position()` returns `#target`'s offset relative to its offset parent, which is `#c` (not `#a`)

I need a function that's equivalent to `$.fn.position()`, but instead returns the position relative to an "offset ancestor" of the target, rather than its direct offset parent. For example: `$("#target").positionRelativeTo("#a")`

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate it based on offset:

```
var topoffset = $('#target').offset().top - $('#a').offset().top;
var leftoffset = $('#target').offset().left - $('#a').offset().left;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of [.parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) and calculate the combined positions that way:

```
var x=0;
var y=0;
$('#target').add($('#target').parentsUntil($('#a').parent())).each(function(){
  x+=$(this).position().left;
  y+=$(this).position().top;
});
alert(x+':'+y);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rDzpy/

Comment: Will this work even if `#a` has parents that have `position: static`?

Comment: @HoraceLoeb i don't know for sure but i think it should

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery extension I made for a project we're working on.
I think this might be what you're looking for.

```
$.fn.relativePositionToAncestor = function (ancestor) {
    var positionedAncestor = $(ancestor);
    var object = $(this);

    var relativeOffset = { left: 0, top: 0 };

    var leftSpacing = parseInt(object.css("margin-left"));
    var topSpacing = parseInt(object.css("margin-top"));

    relativeOffset.left -= leftSpacing;
    relativeOffset.top -= topSpacing;

    var offsetParent = object.offsetParent();

    while (offsetParent[0] !== positionedAncestor[0] && !offsetParent.is('html')) {
        var offsetParentPosition = offsetParent.position();

        var offsetParentPositionLeft = offsetParentPosition.left;
        var offsetParentPositionTop = offsetParentPosition.top;

        relativeOffset.top -= offsetParentPositionTop;
        relativeOffset.left -= offsetParentPositionLeft;

        leftSpacing = parseInt(offsetParent.css("margin-left"));
        leftSpacing += parseInt(offsetParent.css("border-left-width"));
        topSpacing = parseInt(offsetParent.css("margin-top"));
        topSpacing += parseInt(offsetParent.css("border-top-width"));

        relativeOffset.left -= leftSpacing;
        relativeOffset.top -= topSpacing;

        offsetParent = offsetParent.offsetParent();
    }
    return relativeOffset;
};
```